# What's this directory in Node JS bash command?

Tags: bash

Reading the NodeJS page, stumbled upon this bash command:

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

This:

- *Test* it `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}` is empty and prints the home dir *Or* prints the rest
- Exports the result
- executis a script inside the dir

I don't get this `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}` why is it there for?

I'm also not sure what $(...) is doing here, wouldn't print or echo be enough?

Answer (score 1):

`XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is an environment variable that expands to the directory at which programs should store configuration files. By default, this directory is `.config` in your home directory. So in my case, it would expand to `/home/john/.config`.

The command you're asking about seems to check if this environment variable is set. If it is set, it sets `NVM_DIR` to `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm`. Otherwise (if `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set), it sets `NVM_DIR` to `${HOME}/.nvm`. `${HOME}` simply expands to your home directory.

I would imagine that `NVM_DIR` is the directory where this program will store configuration (or other) data. The first line of your command is just choosing where this directory will be, based on if `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set (which it most often is on modern Linux systems, to my knowledge).

Comment: yes but there is a dash after it. that's my problem